# How do I generate a java swing WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL event?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

By what mouse gesture is this scroll type generated?

```
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
  if(e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL) {
     ...
```

Comment: According to the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Mouse-WheelListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html) - `The type of scrolling that occurs, either WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL or WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL, is platform dependent.`. In addition: `Both the type and amount of scrolling can be set via the mouse control panel for the platform.` - I couldn't find a parameter to change on my Windows 7 platform so I can't verify this.

Comment: Thank you, @camickr. I would be interested to know about any way on any platform. I'm trying to find out if I need to handle this case, or somewhat safely ignore it (as I do now).

Comment: So, in Windows, going to mouse settings, and under "Roll the mouse wheel to scroll"  selecting "One screen at a time" instead of "Multiple lines at a time" did not cause events of this particular "scroll type"?